# How to configure Tomcat6 to run Php5

Tags: ubuntu, php5, tomcat6

I am using Tomcat6 as a server and i want to run php5 application on tomcat . Is there anyway to configure tomcat6 to run php on it .?

I am using Ubntu 13.10 to run tomcat6

Answer (score 3):

[Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) is a Java implementation of PHP5.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat supports cgi. So it is possible to run php as cgi.
It might not be the best idea, but it should be possible.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html#Configuration

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on Apache or on Nginx (via fastcgi). Those are two very common use cases. You can't run PHP on Tomcat.

Edit: tomcat doesn't run PHP natively and depending on your requirements you may want to consider alternatives such as Nginx or Apache.

Comment: Just check my answer for it . you can easily do it .

Answer (score 0):

There are there files available which can configure tomcat6 to run php

these ara JavaBridge.jar ,php-script.jar ,php-servelet.jar .You can easily find these files on sourceforge.net .Download these files and copy them to tomcat/lib folder restart tomcat6

write a test php file in  your webapps folder and open it in your browser @localhost:8080/test.php Bingoo..!!
it works

Reference [here](http://ramrajchauhan.blogspot.in/2011/05/php-on-tomcat6-in-ubuntu-linux.html)